# Viva wallet how i create the payment api using node js and mysql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway

> I am working in viva wallet node js and mysql api , i am getting only the api error.

> This is my api , showing only api error.

```
function vivaWalletCreatePayment(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const orderDetails = {
      amount: "100.00",
      customerTrns: "Order #123",
      customer: {
        email: "customer@example.com",
        fullName: "John Doe",
        phone: "1234567890",
        countryCode: "GR",
        requestLang: "en-US",
      },
      paymentTimeout: 0,
      preauth: true,
      allowRecurring: true,
      maxInstallments: 0,
      paymentNotification: true,
      tipAmount: 1,
      disableExactAmount: true,
      disableCash: false,
      disableWallet: false,
      sourceCode: "Default",
      merchantTrns: "Order #123",
      tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
      paymentMethodFees: [
        {
          paymentMethodId: "35",
          fee: 250,
        },
      ],
      cardTokens: ["ct_5d0a4e3a7e04469f82da228ca98fd661"],
    };

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://demo-api.vivapayments.com/checkout/v2/orders",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${clientId}:${clientSecret}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(orderDetails),
    };

    request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
      }

      console.log("Response Status Code:", response.statusCode);

      if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
        console.log("Response Body:", body);
        res.send(body);
      } else {
        console.error("API Error:", body);
        return res.status(response.statusCode).json({ error: "API Error" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  }
}
```

> below is my postman image here i am passing the Reseller API Credentials
> Client ID and secret key, what i have to do for this solution.

> in terminal this error only i am getting
>
> request received
> Response Status Code: 401
> API Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpmeE.jpg)